# Is there a way to use Optional.orElse in eval?

Tags: java, eval, drools

I have a function that returns `Optional` that I want to use in drools eval, e.g.

```
rule "some rule"
  when
    eval(func().orElse(1.0) > 0.0)
  then
    ....
end
```

where `func()` has return type being `Optional<Double>`. The above is giving me compile error because of `orElse`. Is there any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `eval`. It's bad practice. Also you've neglected to include what version of Drools we're talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `eval`.

Assign the function call's result to a Double and do the comparison there. Something like...

```
Double( this > 0.0 ) from func().orElse(1.0)
```

Drools support for Java built-ins and newer functionality (Java 8+) has been hit-or-miss in DRL in my experience, especially with older Drools. If this all doesn't work, your best bet might be to write a method that will wrap the `func().orElse(...)` and resolve to a simple Double and use that instead.